# How to change color of area plot with hover tool (bokeh or holoviews)?

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

How can I build a plot that changes the color of an element when hovering over it? Ideally, I also would not show the legend, but instead, show the label when hovering over the area.

```
import pandas as pd
from holoviews import opts
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

dims = dict(kdims='Year', vdims='Counts')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2001, 2002, 2003], 
                   'col1': [100, 150, 88],
                   'col2': [234, 150, 11]}, index=[1, 2, 3]).set_index('Year').T

objects = []
for col in df.T.columns:
    counts = df.T[[col]].reset_index()
    counts.columns = ['Year', 'Counts']
    tmp = hv.Area(counts, label='-'.join(col), **dims)
    objects.append(tmp)

def product(objects):
    res = objects[0]
    for i, obj in enumerate(objects[1:]):
        res *= obj
    return res

opts.defaults(opts.Area(fill_alpha=0.5))        
overlay = product(objects)
hv.Area.stack(overlay).relabel("Stacked Area Chart")
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve this one?